# How to call functions from an external js file using api.ai

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

I want to perform action from a js file when a certain intent is matchef; For example, If user says, "Show me levis jeans", I want to call a search function from my file which returns a result. If this is not viable, please explain how to make api calls from the agent itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do this with the webhook functionality.

On the page where you configure your intent, go down to the very bottom and click on fulfillment and then check 'use webhook'.

Now go to the fulfillment page and configure you webhook.

There is more info [here](https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook).